# Port Forwarding doesn't work on a Zyxel vmg3312-b10b modem and Ubuntu

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, modem

I'm trying to redirect port 8080 to my application in my laptop on a Zyxel vmg3312-b10b modem and ubuntu. I did the configutations as below :

[image]

I closed both modem's and my operating system's firewall. But I cannot reach to my application from outside network.

Comment: Have you checked you are not behind carrier grade nat? (ie is your ISP doing nat as well?) If you provide  the output od a "tracert -n 8.8.8.8"  we can likely tell this. If your carrier is doing CGN you would need to get them to give you a world-routable IP or use a vpn (service that provides a static ip)  to do the same.

Comment: Here is the output of the tracert command : 8.8.8.8 port 33434: Address family for hostname not supported

Comment: What happens if you download WinMTR or similar and use that?